# How can I select items from a list lower bound to upper bound?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

```
 lowerbound = (CurrentPage - 1) * 10;
 upperbound = (CurrentPage * 10) -1;
```

I have an upper bound and lower bound two integers that specify what is the lowest and highest element between which elements from the List have to be accessed

```
List<string> take = list.Take(upperbound).ToList();
```

How do I select items from a list lower bound to upper bound?

```
foreach (string elemt in take)
{
    HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    div.ID = "div" + elemt;

    Label text = new Label();
    text.Text = elemt;
    div.Controls.Add(text);
    divtest.Controls.Add(div);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301316/c-sharp-equivalent-of-python-slice-operation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<TSource>.Skip(lowerBound).Take(upperBound-lowerBound)
```

MSDN documentation for [Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) and [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

Use List's [GetRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c.aspx) method

```
 take.GetRange(lowerbound, upperbound - lowerbound + 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
list.Skip(lowerBound).Take(upperbound - lowerbound);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ

For items between lowerbound and upperbound

```
list.Skip(lowerbound).Take(upperbound - lowerbound);
```

Or if you have paging use

```
list.Skip((PageNumber - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = lowerBound; i <= upperBound; ++i)
{
   string elemt = take(i);
}
```