# Readable C# equivalent of Python slice operation

Tags: c#, python, slice, equivalent

What is the C# equivalent of Python slice operations?

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
result1 = my_list[2:4]
result2 = my_list[1:]
result3 = my_list[:3]
result4 = my_list[:3] + my_list[4:]
```

[Some of it is covered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301316/c-sharp-equivalent-of-rotating-a-list-using-python-slice-operation), but it is ugly <s>and doesn't address all the uses of slicing</s> to the point of it not obviously answering the question.

Comment: I actually implemented Python-type slicing in ArraySlice<T>. Check it out: https://github.com/henon/SliceAndDice

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The closest is really LINQ [`.Skip()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) and [`.Take()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx)

Example:

```
var result1 = myList.Skip(2).Take(2);
var result2 = myList.Skip(1);
var result3 = myList.Take(3);
var result4 = myList.Take(3).Concat(myList.Skip(4));
```

Comment: +1 You beat me to the trickier examples while I was grabbing MSDN URLs :-) This one is yours. Might I suggest using `result1`, `result2` to match the OP's examples?

Comment: I wish I could use Python (work project), but I guess I'll have to settle for this ugly stuff where I actually have to think when reading it.

Comment: While the answer is very helpful, example is totally wrong except 2nd line. I've suggested an edit.

Comment: This solution is incomplete as it doesn't support negative indexes (e.g., [-5:-4]).

Comment: LINQ `SklpLast` and `TakeLast` methods imitate negative indexes.

Answer (score 47):

As of `C#8` slicing becomes a lot easier for *indexed data structures*.

```
var result1 = myList[2..5]; // end (5) is exclusive
var result2 = myList[1..^0]; // from index 1 to the end 
var result3 = myList[0..3]; // end (3) exclusive
```

Read more about Ranges and indices [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/12/05/take-c-8-0-for-a-spin/) and [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/11/12/building-c-8-0/).

Comment: `List<T>` does not implement indexing with `Range` and the Range pattern requires a member named `Slice` and sadly doesn't support extension methods.

Answer (score 17):

If you have a `List` [GetRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c(v=vs.110).aspx) can come in handy.

From MSDN link:

> A shallow copy of a collection of reference types, or a subset of that
>   collection, contains only the references to the elements of the
>   collection. The objects themselves are not copied. The references in
>   the new list point to the same objects as the references in the
>   original list.

The `Slice` function can then be:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Slice<T>(this List<T> source, int from, int to) => source.GetRange(from, to - from);
```

Negative ranges that python slice supports can also be handled with some loss of cleanliness.

Answer (score 3):

This way you don't have to subtract

```
public static IEnumerable<A> Slice<A> (int from, int to, IEnumerable<A> e) {
    return e.Take (to).Skip (from);
}
```

Comment: Does it support negative indexing? Python does.

Comment: No, take is obviously > 0, Skip also if you take a look at his description. You can strill pass negative without got any exception.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an extension:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Slice<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int start = 0, int end = 0)
{
    start = (start >= 0) ? start : source.Count() + start;
    end = (end > 0) ? end : source.Count() + end;

    return source.Skip(start).Take(end - start);
}
```

Examples:

```
var input = new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
numbers.Slice(1, 4);    // { 1, 2, 3 }
numbers.Slice(-3, -1);  // { 5, 6 }
numbers.Slice(5);       // { 5, 6, 7 }
numbers.Slice(end:-4);  // { 0, 1, 2, 3 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static T[] slice<T>(T[] l, int from, int to)
{
    T[] r = new T[to - from];
    for (int i = from; i < to; i++)
    {
        r[i-from]=l[i];
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Add explanation to your answer

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom extension:

```
public static List<T> Slice<T>(this List<T> li, int start, int end)
{
    if (start < 0)    // support negative indexing
    {
        start = li.Count + start;
    }
    if (end < 0)    // support negative indexing
    {
        end = li.Count + end;
    }
    if (start > li.Count)    // if the start value is too high
    {
        start = li.Count;
    }
    if (end > li.Count)    // if the end value is too high
    {
        end = li.Count;
    }
    var count = end - start;             // calculate count (number of elements)
    return li.GetRange(start, count);    // return a shallow copy of li of count elements
}
```

Some tests:

```
[Fact]
public void Slice_list()
{
    var li1 = new List<char> {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'};
    Assert.Equal(new List<char> {'c', 'd'}, li1.Slice(2, 4));
    Assert.Equal(new List<char> {'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'}, li1.Slice(1, li1.Count));
    Assert.Equal(new List<char> {'a', 'b', 'c'}, li1.Slice(0, 3));
    Assert.Equal(li1, li1.Slice(0, 4).Concat(li1.Slice(4, li1.Count)));
    Assert.Equal(li1, li1.Slice(0, 100));
    Assert.Equal(new List<char>(), li1.Slice(100, 200));

    Assert.Equal(new List<char> {'g'}, li1.Slice(-1, li1.Count));
    Assert.Equal(new List<char> {'f', 'g'}, li1.Slice(-2, li1.Count));
    Assert.Equal(new List<char> {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'}, li1.Slice(0, -1));

    Assert.Equal(new List<char> {'c', 'd', 'e'}, li1.Slice(2, -2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation that follows the JavaScript's [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method which I believe is similar to Pythons implementation:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> slice<T>(List<T> e, int? n1 = null, int? n2 = null)
{
    if (e == null)
        throw new Exception($"source must not be null");
    int iFrom;
    int iTo;
    if (n1 == null)
    {
        iFrom = 0;
        iTo = e.Count;
    }
    else if (n2 == null)
    {
        if (n1 < 0)
        {
            iFrom = e.Count + (int)n1;
            if (iFrom < 0)
                iFrom = 0;
            iTo = e.Count;
        }
        else
        {
            iFrom = (int)n1;
            iTo = e.Count;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (n1 == null)
            throw new Exception("n1 must be an integer if n2 is specified but got null");
        if (n1 < 0)
            throw new Exception($"n1 must be an integer >= 0 if n2 is specified but got {n1}");
        iFrom = (int)n1;
        iTo = (int)n2;
        if (iTo < 0)
            iTo = e.Count + iTo;
        if (iTo <= iFrom)
            iTo = iFrom;
    }


    return e.GetRange(iFrom, iTo - iFrom);
}

public static string[] slice(string[] source, int? n1 = null, int? n2 = null)
{
    return slice(source.ToList(), n1, n2).ToArray();
}

public static object[] slice(object[] source, int? n1 = null, int? n2 = null)
{
    return slice(source.ToList(), n1, n2).ToArray();
}

public static int[] slice(int[] source, int? n1 = null, int? n2 = null)
{
    return slice(source.ToList(), n1, n2).ToArray();
}
```

The above will work with List and Arrays (I implemented str, int, obj).

If there is a more elegant way to implement the Array APIs, please suggest. I'm new to C#.